# Windows 7 MAR/Refurbished version

Tags: windows-7

what's the difference between normal windows and the refurbished (mar) version?

Can I use the refurbished one for new custom pc's? I don't quite get why it's cheaper.

Comment: here for example http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Professional-Refurbished-Service-English/dp/B005KKOOEI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1384803509&sr=8-1&keywords=windows+mar

Comment: Have you read the product description in your link? "This product is an MAR (Microsoft Authorized Refurbisher) package, and the licence governing the installation and use may not convey the same rights as a full retail package. MAR product packages may not contain the same printed documentation or bundled software and hardware which forms part of the full retail package. Prospective purchasers should make themselves aware of any such restrictions before purchasing. Product Description Operating Systems"

Comment: No, i've read the german description on amazon and there was no trace of that information. I was worried the refurbished version only works if you already have some older windows license key - thanks anyway. Could've seen that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new PC requires a version of windows with a new license key installed if purchased from a manufacturer.

A refurbished PC is allowed to use an existing product key (2nd hand if you like) as long as it still comes with its authenticity certificate (COA). This is referred to as MAR (Microsoft Authorised Refurbisher) meaning that Microsoft authorise them to use existing product keys/licenses.

Buying a MAR version of windows means you are technically buying a second hand copy - however, being software, as long as it comes with its COA, will make absolutely no difference at all.

I believe, technically, a MAR version of windows should only be available when purchasing a refurb computer - but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience has been OEM versions and I believe the same applies to "for refurbished" ties the program to only the original computer it is first activated on.  In the event of a failed hard drive a new hard drive will require a "new" or different copy of windows.  The program can't be uninstalled and reinstalled on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

Well as an OEM (or DSP - Delivery Service Partner) version is allowed only in a new computer, a MAR version is allowed only in a refurbished computer. Technically you can install either version anywhere, but this is not legally allowed by Microsoft. So no, you cannot buy a MAR version for a new PC, this would be a violation of EULA and hence illegal. MAR versions are cheaper partly because they are "second-hand" versions (already activated at least once) but also because a refurbished computer usually costs less than $100 and nobody would be willing to pay another $100 ore more to add Windows! They would all install pirated copies! Thus Microsoft keeps the price of MAR versions as low as possible to encourage users buying Genuine Windows for their refurbished PCs. As for the activation, in case the hard disk fails, you can replace it with another new hard disk or SSD. If Windows won't activate automatically, you call Microsoft, explain the situation and they will activate it for you. Don't worry about that. I hope that helps.